# How to change a ProtoMember index for members in a type using Protobuf.net?

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

I have a type like this:

```
[ProtoContract]
class Person {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name {get;set:}
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

Later I realized I need another property `Age` so added it like:

```
[ProtoContract]
class Person {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name {get;set:}
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public int Age {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

But since I am still in development phase, I want to change the `Age` `ProtoMember` index from 3 to 2, and update the `Id` `ProtoMember` appropriately.

Is there a way to do this easily? Or do I have to create another type temporarily to convert it back and forth until I can serialize it to the right type I want in the updated form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the issue is migrating old data? If so, then v2 can do this for you; **however**, I would also be *personally* included to say "meh, Age is #3, Id stays #2" (I can't see huge benefits in changing this number).

But as an example for the more general case:

```
var oldModel = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
// "false" here means "don't apply the normal rules; I'll tell you what to do"
oldModel.Add(typeof(Person), false).Add("Name", "Id");

var newModel = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
// "true" here means it will read from the attributes etc
newModel.Add(typeof(Person), true);

// now: load from an old file, and write to a new:
var obj = oldModel.Deserialize(inFile, null, typeof(Person));
newModel.Serialize(outFile, obj);
```

By having 2 different `RuntimeTypeModel` instances with different configurations you can apply all sorts of odd translations between data. But again - using this *just* so that `Age` is #2 seems massive overkill. Indeed, I would simply make my class:

```
[ProtoContract]
class Person {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name {get;set:}
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

And look! They are magically in order!

Comment: Also Mark, sorry I forgot to say but this is not really old data. So I have the new version serialized to a file with indices 1, 3, 2. So now want to make them 1, 2, 3. So in your code, I just have to change the 2nd line to also add the Age, but in the order I want to have?

Comment: @JoanVenge sure (although note the direction I chose was "old = explicit, new = use the attributes", so it would be "but in the order that they were" - alternatively, just reverse old/new)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the library to help you with this.  So you'll have to write something to update the data if you really need to.

If you have a bunch of data you should probably just leave the field ID's as they are.  It doesn't matter too much.  ID's 1-16 I think use only 1 byte as the field tag, higher numbers use more bytes.

The benefit of leaving the id's as they are is that it gives you forward and backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, I also want backwards and forwards compatibility but since the app is still being developed, wanted it to be cleaner.